# C# object metadata

Tags: c#, object

Is there any way to *glue* metadata to an object in C#?

Context: Framework which is sending messages between peers over the network. Messages can be arbitrary serializable user-defined .NET types.

Of course, when a message is sent by a peer, the framework could wrap the object into a Message class which saves the metadata, and the receiver could unwrap it. However, the processing method of the peer could decide to resend the message to another peer - however, I want to keep the original metadata. The user should not be required to use `Message.RealMessage` all the time except when resending it.

I thought about keeping the wrapped instance in a dictionary and upon resending looking up if there is already a wrapped instance in the dictionary and resending that one, however, as messages may not be resent at all (or resent multiple times) this would require more and more memory.

Any solutions? Maybe C# directly supports gluing additional information to an object? Normally I would go for an internal interface, however, the user would have to derive all its classes from a framework's base class, which is not possible.

Edit: I kind of want to say "here is an object of WrappedMessage but you are only allowed to use the interface provided by the *class* T".

Comment: How would having the CLR do the work possibly be any more memory-efficient than your framework doing it? In any case, the answer to your question is "no". The closest you get is attributes, which apply to types/members/etc, not objects.

Comment: WPF uses attached properties for this kind of thing.  Essentially they are static properties keyed off the instance of the type they are glued on.  The pattern isn't a natural syntax, but with extension methods it may feel more natural to use.

Comment: @siride: It is not a question of memory-efficiency. It is a question whether C# supports it syntactically. It should not add any noise to the user's view.

Comment: @Will: Thanks for the hint, I'm going to look into that and report back.

Comment: @D.R.: you explicitly mentioned concerns about memory efficiency leading to you wanting to avoid rolling your own solution.

Comment: You probably won't/wouldn't want to be able to use DependencyProperties for this, but the pattern would be the same.  Create a static type with extension methods that keep weak references to instances, key off these references (`this object instance`) to retrieve the metadata.  Clear it out if the type is collected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [ConditionalWeakTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx) that should do what you want a little better than using directly a Dictionary.

To quote:

> Enables compilers to dynamically attach object fields to managed objects.

You can ignore the part about the class being for compiler :-)

Comment: Nice, this looks like exactly what I need and what has been described by Will. I'll try it, if it works, I will mark your answer as accepted of course!